# format a JavaScript date using substring

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below method sends date to text box in this format `Wed Sep 14 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0400`.
So i tried to use substring method to get date in this format  `Sep 14 2016`

i have tried to it in below code but it didn't work

it return this error `Uncaught TypeError: date.substring is not a function`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var dateval = $('#<%= txtdate.ClientID %>').val();
        if (dateval != '') {

            var options = {
                selectedDate: dateval,
                size: 'medium',
                width: 960
            }
        } else {
            var options = {
                size: 'medium',
                width: 960
            }
        }
        $('#paginator').datepaginator(options);
        $('#paginator').on('selectedDateChanged', function (event, date) {
            $('#<%= txtdate.ClientID %>').val(date.substring(4, 12));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You should not parse dates on your own. Use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must convert date to string and then use sub string

like this

```
$('#<%= txtdate.ClientID %>').val(date.toString().substring(4, 12));
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `Array.prototype.slice` function.

```
var date = 'Wed Sep 14 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0400';
var formatted = date.split(' ').slice(1, 4).join(' ');
```

You got an error because `date.constructor` is `Date` function, not `String`. To convert it to string you can use `date.toString()` or simply `date + ''`. After it is converted to string, you can call `date.substr(4, 11)`. Notice that if you type `12` instead of `11` it will have an extra space on the end.

Also, there is a difference between `substr` and `substring`. The first one require begin position and length of a string while the second one require begin position and end position of a string.